# How I strip path of source file while writing a compilation rule in makefile?

Tags: makefile

In short: I want to compile sources from different directories, and put object files into current directory.

For example, I have files:

```
test.c
../../lib1/boot.c
../../lib2/startup.c
../common/utils.c
```

(also few files .s (assembly) and .cpp, but I hope this is not important).

All of their object-files I want to be in the current directory:

```
test.o
boot.o
startup.o
utils.o
```

And I can't figure out how to write such rule in my makefile.

For example,

```
%o.: %.c
```

does not work now because `make` can't find a rule to build `boot.o` from `../../lib1/boot.c`, it can only find rule to build `../../lib1/boot.o` from `../../lib1/boot.c`.

I tried to use this:

```
%o.: %.c
 (my compilation line, for example "gcc -c $^ -o $@")
%o.: ../../lib1/%.c
 (my compilation line)
%o.: ../../lib2/%.c
 (my compilation line)
%o.: ../common/%.c
 (my compilation line)
```

and it works. But obviously this is not generic enough, and in addition, some user came to me today and said that his application has also some `../../some_other_lib/common_things.c`, hence my makefile failed. I looked through our project, and found many such cases with a lot of different directories involved. With my approach, I'll have to write a separate rule for each such directory, with identical compilation line. This does not seem good to me.

So my question is: how to make some generic compilation rule that puts (and checks) object files in current directory, while operating with sources in different directories?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered using `VPATH`?

Comment: Idelic, unfortunately, no, I did not try it. See also answer of eriktous here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, took me some time, but finally I found the solution (using some threads on this site by the way):

```
# Defining compilation rules in a way that object files will be produced in current directory, and not in the directory of source files:
all: <List of my targets>

define my_c_rule
$(subst .c,.o,$(notdir $(1))): $(1)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CDEFINES) $$^ -o $$@
endef
$(foreach f, $(CSRC), $(eval $(call my_c_rule, $(f))))
```

`$(CSRC)` contains list of source files with their paths.

Just need to take into account that if earlier I had something like this:

```
.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CDEFINES) $^ -o $@

all: <List of my targets>
```

...now I have to put `all` sentence above the rules which I described in `my_c_rule` procedure. If I don't do this, `make` stops after compiling first source file. This is because old "wildcard" rules like `.c.o` or `%.o: %.c` do not replace `all` as a default target (even being written earlier), but non-wildcard rules like `boot.o: ../../lib1/boot.c` (result of the above macros) do replace the default target in case they are written earlier.

Answer (score 12):

Try to use makefile function `notdir` as this:

```
%.o:    %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $(notdir $@)
```

`$@` must be equal to the full path ex: `../../lib2/startup.o` ad `notdir` will trunk it to: `startup.o`.

With this rule you will be able to compile all your source in the current directory.

Actually, your example is like that:

```
.
└── common
    ├── lib1
    │   └── boot.c
    ├── lib2
    │   └── startup.c
    ├── test
    │   ├── Makefile
    │   └── test.c
    └── utils.c
```

I think i will be better like that:

```
.
├── common
│   ├── lib1
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── obj
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── boot.c
│   ├── lib2
│   │   ├── Makefile
│   │   ├── obj
│   │   └── src
│   │       └── startup.c
│   ├── Makefile
│   ├── obj
│   ├── src
│   │   └── utils.c
│   └── test
│       ├── Makefile
│       ├── obj
│       └── src
│           └── test.c
└── Makefile
```

For that you need all your Makefiles to call the subdirs Makefiles.
and the `src`/`obj` dirs is a separation between your source and objects.

```
SRC := utils.c

OBJ := $(SRC:%.c=%.o)

NAME := project

SRC_D := src
OBJ_D := obj

SUBDIRS := lib1/ \
           lib2/ \
           test/

all: $(NAME) $(SUBDIRS)
    @for dir in $(SUBDIRS); \
    do \
    $(MAKE) -C $$dir; \
    done

$(NAME):    $(OBJ:%.o=$(OBJ_D)/%.o)

$(OBJ_D)/%.o :  $(SRC_D)/%.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Comment: Sirttas, I know about "notdir", but my problem was not in compilation line (which is "gcc ..."). It was in the rule (which is "%.o: %.c"). And I can't see how your example solves the problem. I would appreciate if you explain, because if I understood correctly, in your reply structure of object files will repeat structure of the source files; you just add "src" and "obj" as upper directory to all paths.

Comment: My exemple is not correct you are true, I think you must a recursive makefile compiling `lib1`,  `lib2` and `common`. I will edit.

Comment: Sorry, I can't do it recursively because I don't know which directories my users will use. I need it to work with source directories, whose amount, nesting and names are unknown beforehand. List of source files with their full paths comes as parameter to `make`.

Comment: ok so just use the rule with notdir, it change the content of the compilation line and make one rule for all.

Comment: I can't, because `notdir` works in the compilation line, but does not work inside the rule line. For example `$(notdir %.o): %.c` does not work for me.

Answer (score 10):

The directories can be extracted from the `CSRC` variable with `$(dir ...)` and this list can then be used in the `vpath` directive.

```
vpath %.c $(sort $(dir $(CSRC)))
vpath %.s $(sort $(dir $(SSRC)))
vpath %.cpp $(sort $(dir $(CPPSRC)))
```

(I've thrown in the `sort` function to remove duplicates, but that's not absolutely necessary.)

Now the rules can be kept simple and `make` will search the source files in the list of directories.

```
$(COBJ) := $(notdir $(CSRC))
$(SOBJ) := $(notdir $(SSRC))
$(CPPOBJ) := $(notdir $(CPPSRC))

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(COBJ) $(SOBJ) $(CPPOBJ)
    ....

$(COBJ): %.o: %.c
    ...

$(SOBJ): %.o: %.s
    ...

$(CPPOBJ): %.o: %.cpp
    ...
```

Comment: I suspected that this can be done this way, but I could not find the exact solution because I did not understand how `vpath` works. So I chose another solution. But thank you, and if my solution will require some potential future extensions of the task, I'll take your solution into account.

Comment: `notdir` was exactly what I was looking for.